# SSH from the secondary network interface ip in ec2 running centos7

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7, network-interface

I created a ec2 instance using centos7 image and attached a additional Network interface with a private ip. I have 2 interfaces now eth0 and eth1. Now I want to SSH from another instance in the same subnet using the new interface private ip. How can I do that? (All the interafces and instances are in the same subnet and using same security group.)

```
VPC-172.31.0.0/16
Subnet-172.31.2.0/24 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.2.234  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.31.2.255
        inet6 fe80::862:34ff:fee4:20e2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:62:34:e4:20:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 379  bytes 37642 (36.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 427  bytes 46789 (45.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12  bytes 920 (920.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 920 (920.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein how can i ssh using the new network interface ip

Comment: I notice that the second interface is not listed. Looks like you'll need to tell the operating system that there is a second ENI. It would be something like: [Multiple IPs and ENIs on EC2 in a VPC | Bluemalkin Blog](https://blog.bluemalkin.net/multiple-ips-and-enis-on-ec2-in-a-vpc/). Here's something similar for Ubuntu: [Create and Attach a Second Elastic Network Interface with EIP to EC2 VPC Instance (with Routing) | Lisenet.com :: Linux | Security | Networking](https://www.lisenet.com/2014/create-and-attach-a-second-elastic-network-interface-with-eip-to-ec2-vpc-instance/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about software development -- **not** system administration. See [unix.se], [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), etc.